# Python enumerate(), float object is not iterable

Tags: python

I have a list `a`, then I use `max(a)` to get the max values. Next step I am trying to use `enumerate()` to get the first position of max values. But it notices that I could only use `enumerate()` for int lists? How about float lists? Is there any way to get the 1st position of max values in a float(also with int) list? Thanks a lot

```
a = [1.5, 1.8, 3.1, 4.2, 5.5, 3.2, 4, 2, 1, 5.5, 3, 2.7]
b = max(a)
maxIndex = [i for i, j in enumerate(b) if j == b][0]
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `enumerate(b)`?  `b` is a float, not a list.  Did you mean `enumerate(a)`?

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Simple mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, I think you meant to use `enumerate(a)` not `enumerate(b)`, as `b` is just the max float.

Secondly, you can also do:

```
maxIndex = a.index(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

`max(a)` returns the single highest value- it doesn't return a list (or anything iterable) at all. So therefore you can't use enumerate on it.

Answer (score 2):

One-liner:

```
maxpos = max(enumerate(a), key=lambda p: p[1])[0]
```

Comment: @rkhayrov's answer is great because it only iterates the list once. If it's big, that can be important.

Comment: @Blckknght Well, not really. Both two-pass and one-pass solutions are still O(N), but `a.index(max(a))` is two calls to C runtime, and my solution calls back to lambda on each iteration. That's much bigger overhead. It offers no advantages, at least for list of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
maxIndex = [i for i, j in enumerate(a) if j == b][0]
```

Comment: yep, I made a simple mistake on it. Thanks